# Do I Need A Contract Monad For a Burn Wallet?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, validator, burn

If I make a script address to be a burn address, I end up having a validator that never validates i.e. returns false all the time. Does a Smart Contract that never can validate need an instance of the contract monad to be recognised by the blockchain?

I get that I could just make a Trival instance of the contract monad and that is how I am currently doing it, but I'm curious how would the chain view this?

Answer (score 1):

to help clarify, a plutus smart contract does not need a contract monad.  A contract monad is used by the plutus PAB to create a client side contract that helps prepare and submits the plutus script and required data (inputs, outputs, redeemer, datum, etc).
So back to your question regarding a plutus script that always fails. This script would be no different that any other plutus script, so it would be deployed in the same way with or without the PAB.  When ADA is sent to this script, there would be no way to spend it because the script will always fail.  The only way to spend ADA locked at a script address is to include that script as a witness to the spend, and because the script will always fail, the transaction to spend will also fail.